# How to change attributes of ALL master slides in a KEYNOTE theme at once?

Tags: keynote, themes, template

Is there a way to change multiple masters at once in **Keynote**.  Examples

- Change the background color for ALL slides from grey to green.
- Change all fonts from Copperplate to Garamond
- Insert a company logo onto all slides simultaneously.
- Change the default background to all text boxes to #6699EE

There is a similar question but the accepted answer explains how to do it for ONE master.

This question was asked once before, in November 2011.  Has this situation changed?

Comment: I think it could be useful if you’d *link to the question* you are refering to. This also helps users viewing the other question find your question (and potential answers). Thanks!

Comment: Also, it might help if you tell us what application you're using (i.e. are you using PowerPoint or Keynote?)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that it's possible. Each of the Keynote masters are pretty different items, with completely different fonts, objects, etc. It's a failing of the system.